# No such file or directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

Recently I started development on a discord bot and I keep running into this issue / error which is saying that "Line 23: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Limited Bot\Items\Valkyrie_Helm.json']" even though its correct? Any reasoning or fixes for this?

Here is the file directory:
[image]

```
//Variables
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Discord.Client();
var Token = "";

//Log In
Client.login(Token)

//Item
var ItemsDirectory = "C://Users/Owner/Desktop/Limited Bot/Items";
function ReleaseItem() {
    fs.readdir(ItemsDirectory, function (err, Items) {
        var ItemTable = [];
        Items.forEach(function (Item) {
            var ItemName = path.basename(Item);
            ItemTable.push(ItemName);
        });
        var Item = ItemTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * ItemTable.length)]
        var ItemPath = ItemsDirectory + "/" + Item
        fs.readFile(ItemPath, "utf8", function (err, ItemOverview) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var ItemOvervieww = JSON.parse(ItemOverview);
            console.log(ItemOvervieww.Price)
        });
    });
}

ReleaseItem()
```

Comment: Is it authenticated to you to access the C drive ?

Comment: Yes everything is accessible.

Comment: @Teemu is right, Desktop is not a real folder

Comment: Try to use path.resolve(ItemsDirectory) to resolve the path and do necessary changes in path

Comment: Desktop is real because it works when it loops through the items folder. I think Matthews worked because I removed "+ .json" and it worked but now I'm getting the error: "Line 24: SyntaxError: Unexpected token V in JSON at position 1"

Comment: Just to add if someone stumbles upon this question - you have to name it *.json if you want the json parser to treat it as a json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is named `Valkyrie_Helm`, not `Valkyrie_Helm.json`.